# Can I use Selenium Grid to test multiple machines and website but same browser

Tags: selenium-grid

I have to test multiple machine and each machine have to test different website with same browser. In this case can I use Selenium Grid?
If I can't, are there any way to do that?

Comment: Is that a real user behavior though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it using Grid. I am going to give you a simple example. Create two class of testng and and set the class in testng.xml

Now use code in both classes as below:-

public class Testing {

```
      public static try1 {
         try{

          String baseUrl="https://www.google.com/";        // url on which we have to test
          String nodeurl="http://192.168.10.30:5555/wd/hub";  // ip and port of node remote machine 2 we are using as node for testing. 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/robot/chromedriver.exe");


            // the below line have chrome capability then explorer works dont change it to explorer it doesn't work
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl), DesiredCapabilities.chrome()); 
        driver.get(baseUrl);


        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("BrowserStack");
        element.submit();

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
         }
```

Now configure different site in both classes, set there ips and provide there port as you had set in your other salve machines.

If you want to run them parallel then simply put `parallel="tests"` in your testng.xml

```
<suite name="Test-class Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
```

I Hope it will help you :)

Comment: what happened. Is this not worked for you? you can tell me so I can correct myself if any

Comment: oops sorry it's wrong click
I just want to copy the "public class Testing {..."
\