# How to run selenium tests simultaneously

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I want to run selenium tests simultaneously. But there is a twist here, I don't want to run tests simultaneously on different browsers/different machines.

In my case, I am using selenium to configure my servers from GUI (I am not intended to test anything). For example, I use the following command

```
java -cp <classpath> selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar Package.ClassName param1 param2 param3
```

The above command will start configuring one server using parameters (param1,param2,param3). Simultaneously I want to start another server configuration with different parameters.

If I run the above command once, configurations are good. If the run the above command(with different parameters) by opening 3 instances of putty and run them simultaneously, things are messing up.

I am using the default port '4444' for all the above processes. I thought it might have caused the issue. So, I started selenium in three different ports. and run the above command on three different ports. still, the result is messing up.

I am not sure if selenium grid will help, as I don't want to run tests simultaneously on different browsers/different machines which selenium grid is meant for.

Please help, many thanks :)

Comment: I think you need my two answers on SO ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578758/how-to-run-more-then-one-selenium-testing-suite-on-the-same-machine/32580087#32580087

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389706/can-i-use-selenium-grid-to-test-multiple-machines-and-website-but-same-browser/32390169#32390169

Comment: This may help, it will spin up multiple browsers of the same type on a single machine: https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template